# Mathematica computes wrong eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix

```
 M = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, b}, {0, 0, -b, 0}}
```

that I want to diagonalize. So far, I always used the following and it worked, but for

```
 U = Eigenvectors[M]
 FullSimplify[U.M.Transpose[U]] // MatrixForm
```

I get $$ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 i b \\
 0 & 0 & -2 i b & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

In contrast for a different matrix like

```
M2= {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, A, 0}, {0, A, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

I get from

```
 U2 = Eigenvectors[M2]
 FullSimplify[U2.M2.Transpose[U2]] // MatrixForm
```

the result

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 A & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 A \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ 
as it should be.

**What's the problem here? Why isn't**

```
 FullSimplify[U.M.Transpose[U]] // MatrixForm
```

**diagonal as it should be?**

EDIT:
For

```
 FullSimplify[U.M.Inverse[U]] // MatrixForm
```

I get a diagonal matrix, but then

```
 M3=M+M2 
 U3 = Eigenvectors[M3]
 FullSimplify[U3.M3.Inverse[U3]] // MatrixForm
```

isn't diagonal.

Comment: `M` is not symmetric, so the correct check exploiting the antisymmetry is `U.M.ConjugateTranspose[U]`.

Comment: @J. M. Thanks for your comment. This works for M, but if I define a new matrix as the sum of the two other matrices this does not yield a diagonal matrix. The result is then $$ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & -\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{(A-b) (A+b)}} & \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{(A-b) (A+b)}} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{2 A^2}{\sqrt{(A-b) (A+b)}} & 0 & -\frac{A^2+b^2}{\sqrt{(A-b) (A+b)}} & 0 \\
 -\frac{2 A^2}{\sqrt{(A-b) (A+b)}} & 0 & 0 & \frac{A^2+b^2}{\sqrt{(A-b) (A+b)}} \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

Comment: That would be because the eigenvectors are returned as rows. `Transpose[]` before checking.

Comment: @J. M. oh... yes of course. Thank you so much!

Comment: Okay, read the docs for `Eigensystem[]`, and then try answering your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the relation between an original matrix and the eigenvalue decomposition is the following:

```
m = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];
{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[m];
Norm[Transpose[evec].DiagonalMatrix[eval].Inverse@Transpose[evec]-m]
```

which outputs 0.

So, in order to diagonalize the matrix `m`, we have to evaluate
`Inverse[u].m.u` with `u=Tranpose@Eigenvectors@m`.